# SSH command throw 'Permission denied (publickey)' message error

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm trying to execute an `ssh` command specific `ssh -NL` and I try with other command but in every execution I have this message
`Permission denied (publickey)` I already create my public and private keys in the `.ssh` folder.

So i don't know if somebody has the same problem and found some solution.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

It depend why you have to do tunnelling for git (mentioned in the tags of the question)

[`ssh -NL` is for tunning](https://gist.github.com/rbrooks/2124882) as in *

```
sudo ssh -NL 80:localhost:80 root@<IP or hostname>
```

- `-N` - Just set up the tunnel. Do not prepare a command stream.
- `-L` - Local. Create a "Forward Tunnel". Forward local port 80 to remote port 80 via SSH (which is on port 22).

That means a simply `ssh -T user@server` should work first.
Check ssh -Tv user@server to see which public key is used, and make sure that public key is registered on the remote server side in `~user/.ssh/authorized_keys`.